# How can i mock database calls without a library?

Tags: database, go, mocking

i've been trying to wrap my head around unit testing, dependency injection, tdd and all that stuff and i've been stuck on testing functions that make database calls, for example.

Let's say you have a PostgresStore struct that takes in a Database interface, which has a Query() method.

```golang
type PostgresStore struct {
    db Database
}

type Database interface {
    Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
}
```

And your PostgresStore has a GetPatients method, which calls database query.

```golang
func (p *PostgresStore) GetPatients() ([]Patient, error) {
    rows, err := p.db.Query("SELECT id, name, age, insurance FROM patients")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    items := []Patient{}
    for rows.Next() {
        var i Patient
        if err := rows.Scan(
            &i.ID,
            &i.Name,
            &i.Surname,
            &i.Age,
            &i.InsuranceCompany,
        ); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        items = append(items, i)
    }
    if err := rows.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return items, nil
}
```

In the real implementation, you would just pass a *sql.DB as Database argument, but how would you guys write a unit test with a fake database struct?

Comment: AFAICT your primary problem is that your `Database` interface is directly dependent on a type for which there is no easy way to provide valid test values, namely `*sql.Rows`. So you either should not be mocking `Database` but instead you should implement a mock [`database/sql/driver`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver@go1.20). Or you need to change the interface to not depend on a type which you no control over, but instead on a type over which you have all the control that you could possibly need (i.e. an interface type).

Comment: Hey man, thats for the answer. Could you please point me to some resources or github projects that implement what you just explained? I'm having a hard time figuring this out haha. Thanks

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't. `GetPatient` doesn't do anything but interact with the DB, so testing it with a mocked DB has limited value. I would unit test whatever calls `GetPatient` with a mock `Store`, and only *integration* test `PostgresStore` itself with a test PostgreSQL DB.

Answer (score 2):

let me try to clarify some of your doubts. First of all, I'm gonna share a working example to better understand what's going on. Then, I'm gonna mention all of the relevant aspects.

##### `repo/db.go`

```golang
package repo

import "database/sql"

type Patient struct {
    ID               int
    Name             string
    Surname          string
    Age              int
    InsuranceCompany string
}

type PostgresStore struct {
    // rely on the generic DB provided by the "sql" package
    db *sql.DB
}

func (p *PostgresStore) GetPatient(id int) ([]Patient, error) {
    rows, err := p.db.Query("SELECT id, name, age, insurance FROM patients")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    items := []Patient{}
    for rows.Next() {
        var i Patient
        if err := rows.Scan(
            &i.ID,
            &i.Name,
            &i.Surname,
            &i.Age,
            &i.InsuranceCompany,
        ); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        items = append(items, i)
    }
    if err := rows.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return items, nil
}
```

Here, the only relevant change is how you define the `PostgresStore` struct. As the `db` field, you should rely on the generic `DB` provided by the `database/sql` package of the Go Standard Library. Thanks to this, it's trivial to swap its implementation with a fake one, as we're gonna see later.

> Please note that in the `GetPatient` method you're accepting an `id` parameter but you're not using it. Your query is more suitable to a method like `GetAllPatients` or something like that. Be sure to fix it accordingly.

##### `repo/db_test.go`

```golang
package repo

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestGetPatient(t *testing.T) {
    // 1. set up fake db and mock
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("err not expected: %v", err)
    }

    // 2. configure the mock. What we expect (query or command)? The outcome (error vs no error).
    rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "name", "surname", "age", "insurance"}).AddRow(1, "john", "doe", 23, "insurance-test")
    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT id, name, age, insurance FROM patients").WillReturnRows(rows)

    // 3. instantiate the PostgresStore with the fake db
    sut := &PostgresStore{
        db: db,
    }

    // 4. invoke the action we've to test
    got, err := sut.GetPatient(1)

    // 5. assert the result
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Contains(t, got, Patient{1, "john", "doe", 23, "insurance-test"})
}
```

Here, there are a lot to cover. First, you can check the comments within the code that give you a better idea of each step. In the code, we're relying on the package `github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock` that allows us to easily mock a database client.

Obviously, the purpose of this code is to give a general idea on how to implement your needs. It can be written in a better way but it can be a good starting point for writing tests in this scenario.

Let me know if this helps, thanks!